# how to find a class and apply a style with jquery?

Tags: jquery, css, height, jquery-ui-accordion

i have this example in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/patrioticcow/W7e3K/3/) of a accordion only made with css3, no js.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="ac-container">
    <div>
        <input id="ac-1" name="accordion-1" type="radio" checked />
        <label for="ac-1">About us</label>
        <article class="ac-small">
            <p id="test_small">test</p> <-- this tag will come from php
        </article>
    </div>
    <div>
        <input id="ac-2" name="accordion-1" type="radio" />
        <label for="ac-2">How we work</label>
        <article class="ac-medium">
            <p id="test_medium">test</p>
        </article>
    </div>
</div>​
```

**css:**

```
.ac-container input:checked ~ article.ac-small{
    height: 140px;
}
.ac-container input:checked ~ article.ac-medium{
    height: 180px;
}
.ac-container input:checked ~ article.ac-large{
   /* height: 240px;*/
}
```

the issue i have is that the height is already set, and i add the content with php and i'm not sure how much content will be so i need to have a dynamic height.

the php will be loading the p tag so i can find the height like this:

```
var v = $("#test_small").height();

// add the height to the .ac-small
$('.ac-container input:checked article.ac-small').css("height", v+'px');
```

the problem i have is that that the css wont apply to the selector, i believe the selector `$('.ac-container input:checked article.ac-small')` is wrong or something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try

```
$('.ac-container input:checked').parent('div').children('article.ac-small').css("height", v+'px');
```

Comment: You could have written it with one selector.

Comment: I saw the post made by jeff b. I do like the single selector approach.  I thought I would give another method.

Comment: just need to add on click event for the `input #ac-1` and so on

Answer (score 1):

Your selector is wrong. Allow me to explain to you what that selector fetches:

```
$('.ac-container input:checked article.ac-small')
```

It will select the `<article>` elements with class `ac-small` that exist inside of checked input that exist inside an element `ac-container` element.

Well you can't have element **inside** of an input...

In the `css` you wrote the selector right:

```
.ac-container input:checked ~ article.ac-small{
    height: 140px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**First:**
You have to change the id to a class

```
var v = $(".ac-small").height();
```

**Second:**
If you want to get the sibling of your input you have to do it:
Get the checked input inside the container, when found get it article sibling and then set the css.

```
$('.ac-container').find('input:checked').siblings('article').css("height", v+'px');
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to use the [next sibling selector](http://api.jquery.com/next-siblings-selector/).  `~` selects the next sibling that matches that selector, as opposed to the child with that selector:

```
$('.ac-container input:checked ~ article.ac-small')
```

You could also write this as:

```
$('.ac-container').find('input:checked').siblings('article.ac-small')
```

Or more accurately (for next sibling):

```
$('.ac-container').find('input:checked').nextAll('article.ac-small')
```

Answer (score 0):

You do this

```
var v = $("#ac-small").height();
```

But you don't have any element with an id of "ac-small".